# Non-spreading wave packets

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, dimensional-analysis, textbook-erratum

I am reading an article (Nonspreading wave packets, by Michael Berry, [*Am. J. Phys.* **47**, 264 (1979)](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.11855), [author eprint](https://michaelberryphysics.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/berry078.pdf)), and I have some questions about the maths within. First of all they take a wave function packet that at $t = 0$ is

$$\psi(x, 0) = \mathrm{Ai}\mathopen{}\left(\frac{B x}{\hbar ^{2/3}}\right)\tag{1}$$

Where $\mathrm{Ai}$ denotes the Airy function.

$B$ is an arbitrary constant. According to the Schrödinger equation, the wave packet evolves as

$$\psi(x, t) = \mathrm{Ai}\mathopen{}\left[\frac{B}{\hbar^{2/3}}\left(x - \frac{B^3 t^2}{4m^2}\right)\right] \exp\left((i B^3 t/ 2m\hbar)[x - (B^3t^2/6m^2)]\right)\tag{3}$$
and Berry claims that

> It's clear that $|\psi|^2$ does propagate without spreading, and accelerates to the right with velocity $B^3t^2/2m^2$.

**Question 1**: Shouldn't it be $b^3t/2m^2$?

A few lines later, it says something about the centre of gravity of a wave packet: ma **question** is now: how do I find, mathematically, the centre of gravity of a wave packet?

Also it says that

> to explain why the Airy packet is the only one that does not spread, we first note that a necessary condition for ANY probability density to propagate unchanged in form is that its semiclassical representation translates rigidly along $x$ as time elapses.

**Question 3** Is this a theorem? I never heard of this "necessary condition", so where does it come from?

Comment: Yes I think the concept of the question is actually important as coherent states are examples of non-spreading wave packets, and Schrodinger actually found an early solution to this problem.  It would be much better if your question was self-contained.

Comment: A copy of the paper can be found here: http://www.fisicafundamental.net/relicario/doc/berry078.pdf